# 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied in Chrome

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, google-chrome

I installed a new certificate on IIS7.

After I installed the certificate, I opened the site in Chrome and received the following message: 
[image]

I clicked Ok and now when I browse to the site in Chrome, I get an error:

```
403 - Forbidden: Access is denied
```

If I browse in Incognito, I get the message again and if I click Cancel, I can browse the site.

When I go back to a normal browsing window, I get the Access is denied error again.

I don't get the error in Edge.

(If I click on Certificate information, it says "This CA Root certificate is not trusted.")

Comment: What site? What certificate?

Comment: I'm not sure where it is getting that certificate from. It's not an actual certificate.

Comment: You didn't install a real certificate on a site in IIS?

Comment: No, the site has a valid certificate. It seems that there is an invalid certificate installed on my PC. (I've never had to select a certificate for an HTTPS site before?)

Comment: @garethTheRed, brilliant, thank you. Can you post your answer as an answer so that I can mark it as a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have accidentally configured *client authentication* on your IIS server.  The server now expects your browser to send a certificate to the server in order to authenticate you.

Start the IIS Management Console and with your site selected in the left-hand pane, open the **SSL Settings** page.

You need to have **Require SSL** checked in order to enable SSL/TLS on the server (for HTTPS) and also need to ensure that **Client certificates:** is set to **Ignore** so that IIS doesn't instruct the browser to send a client authentication certificate.